# Is there a function key lock or something like that on a Mac?

Tags: mac

For instance, I have a program that has a shortcut for Shift+F11, but of course on my MacBook Pro that's a volume button so I have to hit Fn+Shift+F11.  Is there a way to avoid hitting the function key all the time?  Not a big deal, just curious.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Settings -> Keyboard -> "Use all F1, F2 etc keys as standard function keys"

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure when this changed, but on my Mac running macOS Ventura, you have to dig a bit deeper than the screenshot in the accepted answer.

First, go to System Settings → Keyboard. Then click "Keyboard Shortcuts...".

[image: System settings → Keyboard dialog]

In there, navigate to Functions keys.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts → Function Keys dialog]

And there you will find the setting.

Answer (score 3):

You may like [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/). Here is a description from it's website:

> FunctionFlip's purpose is simply to
>   disable the special features — rewind,
>   play, mute, etc. — on the function
>   keys. For example, if you "flip" F7,
>   F8, and F9, those keys — only those
>   keys — will revert back to normal F
>   keys. Press the fn key with the
>   special key to get the special
>   function back. That is, the "special"
>   and "normal" functions are flipped.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I was after something JUST like this!

Comment: Is there any equivalent of this for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an external keyboard for a mac, check the external keyboard for a f-key lock button. On my logitech it is on the escape key.

*(I just spent half an hour figuring it out!)*